# berkeley db java compilation problem

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I am new to berkeley db and i installed the berkeley db  (not the java version ) and if i try to run the java example program it says

```
`SimpleDA.java:13: package com.sleepycat.db does not exist
import com.sleepycat.db.DatabaseException;
                   ^
```

there is no jar library how can i include the lib in java path ....

`

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a Java example program that needs classes from the `com.sleepycat.db` package, you'll have to get those .class files into the CLASSPATH.  Your .lib does you no good.

[Download the JAR](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) and add it to your CLASSPATH when you run - your exception will go away.